# Export an excel file to txt with same formatting

Tags: excel, text, formatting, vba

I have an excel file written in this way:

```
187712  201    37     0.18   
2525    580    149    0.25   
136829  137    43     0.31
```

I need to export this file with same spaces, same formatting in a txt file. How can i do it? I've tryied `Save As | Formatted Text (Space Delimited) (*.prn)` but not working because i have an issue on the last column. Is there a macro? Thanks.

EDIT: i tryied a macro:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim output As String
    For Each r In Range("A1:L504").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & " " & c.Value
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Open "D:\MyPath\text.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

but the result is

```
187712  201    37     0.18   
2525 580  149    0.25   
136829  137    43     0.31
```

These values are only an example because there are about 504 columns!! Anyway the problem is that if in the first column there is a value shorter then the others it lost the formatting like the second row as you can see.

Comment: You show four fields, right-justified.  How many characters wide do you want each field to be??

Comment: the number of characters it's variable. It depends from the value. Anyway, for example the first field has max characters number equal  at 6. But a value could be 3.. But my result must be as you see on the beginning of my question.. I don't know if it's clear

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with that also numerous times, the only way I found was with a VBA function I created (the tricky part is determining the "widest" column for plain-text layout).  Fair warning: I didn't build a lot "smarts" into this, the output can be a little quirky.

Usage:
Select the cells you want formatted to plain-text, then run the macro (I have the macro assigned to a button, I use it all the time!).  If the top row is center-aligned, then let's /assume/ it's a header.  And watch for right-aligned columns, and output those right-aligned.

The marco will copy the desired output to the clip-board, then paste the result in Notepad (or similar) to do with as desired.

Example output (I threw in some headers)

```
CustId  Views  Selected  Cost
187712    201        37  0.18
  2525    580       149  0.25
136829    137        43  0.31
```

The code:

```
Sub FormatSelectionToPlainText()
  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ' Author: Jay R. Ohman
  ' Ohman Automation Corp., http://www.OhmanCorp.com
  ' ** disclaimer and release: I am NOT an expert  **
  ' ** programmer, use my coding at your own risk! **
  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim rFound As Range, RngCol1 As Integer, RngRow1 As Integer, ActCol As Integer, ActRow As Integer, x As Integer
  Dim MaxCellLen() As Variant, CellAlignRight() As Variant, HdrLen() As Variant, xDbg As Boolean, xVal As Variant
  Dim SepSpace As Integer, RetStr As String, RetLen As Integer, MsgStr As String, HasHdr As Boolean
  Dim GeneralIsRightAlignedFactor As Single, TotalRows As Integer
  Dim oClip As DataObject

  xDbg = True                                                        ' output stuff to the immediate window?
  GeneralIsRightAlignedFactor = 0.75                                 ' threshhold for deeming a column as right-aligned
  Set oClip = New DataObject
  MsgStr = "(looking for top row to be center aligned as header)"
  If MsgBox("Are the cells to be copied selected?" & vbCrLf & MsgStr, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Auto-Fill Time Slots") = vbYes Then
    If (Selection Is Nothing) Then
      MsgBox "Nothing Selected."
    Else
      SepSpace = 2                                                   ' number of spaces between columns
      RetLen = 0
      HasHdr = True
      Set rFound = Selection
      RngCol1 = rFound.Column
      RngRow1 = rFound.Row
      Debug.Print Selection.Columns.Count
      ReDim Preserve MaxCellLen(Selection.Columns.Count)             ' max cell length
      ReDim Preserve CellAlignRight(Selection.Columns.Count)         ' track the cell alignment
      ReDim Preserve HdrLen(Selection.Columns.Count)                 ' header row max cell length
      For ActCol = RngCol1 To RngCol1 + Selection.Columns.Count - 1
        x = (ActCol - RngCol1 + 1)
        ' If xDbg Then Debug.Print Cells(RngRow1, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment
        If (Cells(RngRow1, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment <> xlCenter) And (Cells(RngRow1, ActCol).Value <> "") Then HasHdr = False
        HdrLen(x) = IIf(HasHdr, Len(Cells(RngRow1, ActCol).Value), 0)
        MaxCellLen(x) = 0
        CellAlignRight(x) = 0
      Next
      If xDbg Then Debug.Print "HasHdr: " & HasHdr
      TotalRows = (RngRow1 + Selection.Rows.Count) - (RngRow1 + IIf(HasHdr, 1, 0))
      For ActCol = RngCol1 To RngCol1 + Selection.Columns.Count - 1  ' go find the longest text in each column
        x = (ActCol - RngCol1 + 1)
        xVal = IIf(HasHdr, 1, 0)
        For ActRow = RngRow1 + xVal To RngRow1 + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
          ' If xDbg Then Debug.Print Cells(ActRow, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment
          xVal = Cells(ActRow, ActCol).Value
          If (MaxCellLen(x) < Len(Cells(ActRow, ActCol).Value)) Then MaxCellLen(x) = Len(xVal)
          If (Cells(ActRow, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight) Or _
              ((Cells(ActRow, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral) And (IsDate(xVal) Or IsNumeric(xVal))) Then _
                  CellAlignRight(x) = CellAlignRight(x) + 1
        Next
        If xDbg Then Debug.Print "Max Length for Column " & ActCol & ": " & MaxCellLen(x) & _
            ", CellAlignRight.Count: " & CellAlignRight(x) & "/" & TotalRows
        RetLen = RetLen + MaxCellLen(x) + SepSpace
      Next
      RetLen = RetLen - SepSpace                                     ' subtract that last separator space
      If HasHdr Then
        For ActCol = RngCol1 To RngCol1 + Selection.Columns.Count - 1
          x = (ActCol - RngCol1 + 1)
          If (HdrLen(x) > MaxCellLen(x)) Then MaxCellLen(x) = HdrLen(x)
        Next
      End If
      RetStr = ""                                                    ' build the output text
      For ActRow = RngRow1 To RngRow1 + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
        For ActCol = RngCol1 To RngCol1 + Selection.Columns.Count - 1
          x = (ActCol - RngCol1 + 1)
          MsgStr = Cells(ActRow, ActCol).Value                       ' re-use string variable
                                                                     ' format for right-aligned
          If (CellAlignRight(x) / TotalRows >= GeneralIsRightAlignedFactor) And (Not (HasHdr And (ActRow = 1))) Or (Cells(ActRow, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight) Then    ' aligned right
            RetStr = RetStr & Space(MaxCellLen(x) - Len(MsgStr)) & MsgStr
          ElseIf (Cells(ActRow, ActCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter) Then
            xVal = Fix((MaxCellLen(x) - Len(MsgStr)) / 2)
            RetStr = RetStr & Space(xVal) & MsgStr & Space(MaxCellLen(x) - Len(MsgStr) - xVal)
          Else
            RetStr = RetStr & MsgStr & Space(MaxCellLen(x) - Len(MsgStr))
          End If
          If ((ActCol - RngCol1) + 1 < UBound(MaxCellLen)) Then RetStr = RetStr & Space(SepSpace)
        Next
        RetStr = RetStr & vbCrLf
      Next
      oClip.SetText RetStr
      oClip.PutInClipboard
      MsgBox ("The selection has been copied to clipboard." & vbCrLf & "Max line length: " & RetLen)
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox ("Have a nice day. :)")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i updated my question. As you can see i tryied with a macro and it works until it find a different number of characters in the first column.i need to mantain same spaces between the columns

Comment: I have answere you above

Comment: In case you missed it, I revised my answer with a VBA script that should do what you need.

Comment: I just gotta say, so frustrating, I share my code I spent over 5 hours perfecting, and received zero reward in the reputation based site.  Bummer.

Comment: How can i use your code if i want it from a csv file?

Comment: In Excel 2007 and newer: File > Open > Browse > (bottom-right drop-down) change to "Text Files" (x.prn, x.txt, x.csv) > browse to your file and select.  Excel should imported the comma-serarated-values without any problem.  Once the data is imported into Excel, then the code will work.  (edit: asterisk don't work in StackExchange, so I used x)

Answer (score 1):

Your posted data shows fixed fields with field-widths of 8,7,7,4 (each field is a combination of characters and trailing blanks).  These can be adjusted as necessary in the macro below.  Also adjust the folder name to suit your needs:

```
Sub FixedField()

    Dim fld(1 To 4) As Long
    Dim V(1 To 4) As String
    Dim N As Long, L As Long
    Dim K As Long

    fld(1) = 8
    fld(2) = 7
    fld(3) = 7
    fld(4) = 4
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Close #1
    Open "c:\TestFolder\test.txt" For Output As #1

    For L = 1 To N
        outpt = ""
        For K = 1 To 4
            V(K) = Cells(L, K).Text
            While Len(V(K)) <> fld(K)
                V(K) = V(K) & " "
            Wend
            outpt = outpt & V(K)
        Next K
        MsgBox outpt
        Print #1, outpt
    Next L
    Close #1
End Sub
```

It is also assumed that the data starts in column A.